Connections on principle G-bundles via parallel transport
Suppose we are given a principle $G$-bundle $P\overset{\pi}{\to}M$ and let $\mathfrak{g}$ denote the Lie algebra of $G$. Normally one defines a connection on the principle $G$-bundle $P\overset{\pi}{\to}M$ as an $\omega\in\Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ such that

$R_g^*\omega = Ad_{g^{-1}}\circ\omega$ for $g\in G$, where $R_g:P\to P$ is the right multiplication map and $Ad:G\times\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}:g,\xi\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0}g\exp(t\xi)g^{-1}$ is the adjoint action.
It is a left inverse of the infinitesimal action of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. given an element $\xi\in\mathfrak{g}$ we define a vector field $X_\xi(p) = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t = 0}\exp(t\xi)\cdot p$ then $\omega(X_\xi) = \xi$.

However, in general on a fibre bundle, which we will also denote $P\overset{\pi}{\to}M$, one defines an Ehresmann connection as complement $H$ to the vertical bundle $V = \ker d\pi$, such that $TP = V\oplus H$. From such a splitting we obtain a way of horizontally lifting a path $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ to a path $\gamma_p:[0,\epsilon)\to M$ such that $\gamma_p(0) = p\in P_{\gamma(0)}$, $\pi(\gamma_p(t)) = \gamma(t)$ and $d\pi(\dot{\gamma}_p(t)) = \dot{\gamma}(t)$ for all $t\in[0,\epsilon)$. Moreover, this defines a parallel transport map $\tau_\gamma^s:P_{\gamma(0)}\to P_{\gamma(s)}:p\mapsto \gamma_p(s)$.
Now consider the following: Suppose we are given a principle $G$-bundle $P\overset{\pi}{\to}M$ and a Ehresmann connection on $P\overset{\pi}{\to}M$ as a fibre bundle such that the parallel transport is $G$-equivariant. Can we then say that the Ehresmann connection comes from a principle $G$-bundle connection somehow? Moreover, how are there related?

The first relevant observation to make is that for a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P\to M$, the vertical distribution $\ker d\pi$ is naturally isomorphic to $\mathfrak{g}\times P$, (as $G$ equivariant vector bundles), by the map $\varphi:(\xi,p)\mapsto \frac{d}{dt}\vert_{t=0}\exp(t\xi)p$. Since $G$ acts freely transitively, the image of this map is a subbundle of $V$, and since the fibers of $P\to M$ are $\dim G=\dim \mathfrak{g}$ dimensional, this map surjects onto $V$.
Now given a principal bundle connection $\omega\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ we can naturally obtain a splitting of $TP$. Post composing $\omega$ by $\varphi$ yields $\omega':TP\to V$, which splits the exact sequence $$0\to V\to TP\to \pi^*TM\to 0$$
If $P\to M$ is equipped with a $G$-equivariant Ehresmann connection, i.e. parallel transport commutes with the $G$ action, the image of $\pi^*TM$ under the splitting is invariant under the $G$ action. If $\rho: \pi^*TM\to TP$ is the splitting map, then one yields a projection $TP\to V$ by $1-\rho$. Invariance of $\pi^*TM$ means that $1-\rho$ is a $G$-equivariant morphism and hence $\omega=\varphi^{-1}\circ (1-\rho)\in \Omega^1(P,\mathfrak{g})$ is a principal $G$-bundle connection. (I skipped proving that $\omega$ sends the fundamental vector fields to itself, this is a short check.)

Thanks for the answer. I don't fully understand what you mean that $\pi^*TM$ is invariant under the G action and how this follows from the fact that the parallel transport is $G$-equivariant.
